# Google Maps API Drawing Rectangle

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This is the meat of the code I am using and I am not getting errors, but I am not seeing the points that are in the area of the rectangle. Any help would be appreciated:

```
`enter code here`/** @this {google.maps.Rectangle} */
function showNewRect(event) {
 var ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
var sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();
google.maps.event.addlistener(rectangle, "bounds_changed", function(){
  document.getElementById("map-selected").innerHTML=rectangle.getBounds();
  var rectA = (ne*sw);
 })


}
```

function listSelected () {

var inside = $.map( sites, function ( s ) {

```
  var d;

  if ( ( (d = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation( s.position )) <= rectA  ) )
     return s.location + ' ('+(Math.round(d/100)/10)+' km)';
      $('#map-selected').html( inside.sort().join('') );
```

});

```
}


    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function( rectangle )    {

   selectedArea = rectangle;
  listSelected();

  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'center_changed', listSelected);
  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'bounds_changed', listSelected);I am working with the Google maps API and I have a map I am drawing on with a rectangle. I need to have a user draw the rectangle, and on the map there will be predefined locations, that when the rectangle crosses the locations there will be details of each location put into a list.
```

This is an example:

http://hmoodesigns.com/ksi/

I have an example using the circle draw tool, which I can get to work fine, but the rectangle tool I have not been able to have this identify the points on the map.

How can I check for these points without having a predefined rectangle on the page?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When the Rectangle has been drawn iterate over the locations and use the method `contains()` of the Rectangle's `bounds` to test if the LatLng's are within the bounds of the Rectangle